# Jasper Report export crashes

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver, crosstab

I have a crosstab report that outputs 75 pages.
When I do an export to Excel, after 2-3 mins, it crashes and says "An id is required to lookup a FlowDefinition".

The output of the query contains less than 100,000 rows and the query itself takes 25 secs to execute. (from Naivcat)
After this, jasper server takes some more time to fill the report.
But exporting does not work.

FYI - I have changed the Crosstab limit to 1000000 from the default 100000.

```
#limit the crosstab bucket/measure count to prevent out of memory errors
net.sf.jasperreports.crosstab.bucket.measure.limit=10000000

#suppress page and column footers and all but the first page and column headers when     exporting to XLS
net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.1=pageHeader
net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.2=pageFooter
net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.3=columnHeader
net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.4=columnFooter

# report exporter hints override export parameters
net.sf.jasperreports.export.parameters.override.report.hints=false
```

Thanks
Ravi

Comment: what do you mean with "it crashes"? is there an exception? The flow id is an error that occurs mainly if the session expired or when the user hit back button in the browser.

Comment: Yes.. it is because the session expires that the error occurs. Is there a way to speed up the export process.

Comment: actually if possible, please post your JRXML and excel specific configurations in jasperreports.properties

Comment: Please find in the main post the relevant lines in jasperreports.properties.

Comment: do you use page X of Y for page numbers

Comment: I dont know what it means but in my output on each page it does shown "Page 1 of 75" etc... Did you mean this?

Comment: I'm also facing same issue but it fails only first time with the same flowid error. If I hit submit again then it shows output. After cleaning browser history it fails first time.
Fails in chrome and IE, in mozilla asks to send request again and proceeds.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the browser dependency, I had the same issue then i ran the report in Google Chrome, now my report is working.

So I would advice check with Chrome or whatever you are using just try in other browser.

Comment: Chrome is what I use. Do not think the browser is the problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the total number of pages and just show "Page 1" instead of "Page 1 of 75" - this should improve the report generation significantly because JR would not need to re-evaluate each page to add the total number of pages.

Comment: I understand that but how do you do it ?

Comment: edit the JRXML - there is a pageheader or pagefooter section which holds the fields for the page numbers.